# Manage large amount of files

Tags: php, database, web, filesystems, centos

My website is running on CentOS 6.3 x64 dedicated server, 2 x 1.5 Tb mirrored RAID HDD. There is a folder containing images uploaded by users. Currently there are about 1 million files. Average size of an image is about 30-70 kb.

Everything works great so far (except Midnight Commander which takes several seconds to step inside the folder), but this amount will continue growing to several millions, may be to tens of millions, or even more. Assume that upload:delete ratio is between 100:1 and 1000:1. There is also update function, but it can be represented as delete + upload.

Here is my question: what is the best way to manage such amount of files? Is filesystem OK for that or there is some better technology? May be some NoSQL-like technology, or something like that?

Comment: I would suggest Hadoop's HDFS and hbase. You can use hadoop' stream api for any operations on them... BTW you did not mention what type of operations you do on them. *ALSO I disagree with why this question is downvoted.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True Filesystem should be used for storing files and not an database. But is not designed to look with an very large number (millions will cause lag) of files within 1 directory.

What you can do is to create an three map structure based on filename + timestamp this should optimize the directory/file lookup when dealing with lots of files.

1. concat filename + timestamp
2. calculate md5 hash from step 1
3. b2d03b39b071d2153efd7f1aea5ed5d5 is your md5 hash as example create this map structure b2d/03b/39b

**Note that you now also partition images based on hash parts so watch out because you can overwrite images and this will keep an low number of images within 1 directory.**

**Extra note you should modify your PHP code and redesign your table to take full advantage of this approach.**

Comment: "Structure" - you mean folders structure, right? To regroup one large FS folder into several smaller folders?

Comment: yes "three map structure" i indeed mean "folder" with that. yes indeed regroup the large directory with many files in several smaller folders with lesser files . But using ZFS should also give an boost in performance (like Calimero said)..

Comment: Agreed, this is a common strategy to deal with huge file number in a single folder - split them across a single criteria. Advantage : this can be done as many times as necesary and scales well. Inconvenient : you have to move your current files to match this new scheme (may take a while).

Answer (score 1):

Filesystem is suitable for storing files, which is what you're doing.

You may consider trying alternative filesystem types though (I've been told ZFS offer great performance with listing large amounts of small files)

Comment: What amount of files is OK, and after what amount should I consider to move to separate FS?

Comment: I think you might as well try it right now, since you already have 1 million+ and you are already experiencing slowness.

Comment: Well, not really. Website works great. Midnight commander is slow, but it is expectable - it have to read the folder's content, allocate memory, sort file list, and so on. And website just provides URLs to the files, no file enumeration and etc.

Comment: So you're not planning any global file management here. Then why change anything at all ?

Comment: Dbs are to be considered if you want to store complex metadata & run queries on it, alternative FSs can solve performance problems.

Comment: Right, I'm not planning any complex file management. I was just worried about amount of files, nothing else. This is my first application that stores so much files (in my modest experience).